# Python - Inserción de un elemento en la lista del value de un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x

A la hora de **insertar** un elemento en un **diccionario** mediante el método propuesto `def insert(self,col,data)`, he programado dentro de él:

```
self.db[col] = data
```

Como resultado a la hora de emplear el método en la consola obtenemos:

```
db.insert("col1",[1,2,3])
db.imprimir()
>> {'col1': [1,2,3]}
```

A la hora de realizar un search mediante un query (`SELECT`, `WHERE`, etc.), obtenemos:

```
db.search('SELECT col1')
>> [1,2,3]
```

Bien, el problema reside en que quiero que en el método `insert`, el data se inserte en el primer elemento de la lista de colección 1. Esquema:

[image: Esquema a seguir]

Dado este esquema, el método `insert` que implemento arriba, sería incorrecto. El objetivo sería este:

```
db.insert("col1",2)
db.insert("col1",3)
db.insert("col1",4)
db.insert("col1",4)
db.search('SELECT col1')
>> [2,3,4,4]
db.search('SELECT col1 WHERE = 4')
>> [4, 4]
```

Hemos implementado en otro `.py` la clase nodo y la clase Lista (con métodos de búsqueda, inserción, etc.).

Ahora el paso sería realizar el **insert en una lista**, ¿alguien podría proponer con algún ejemplo una posible solución? ¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Una cuestión de concepto: si estás insertando *items* a una lista, en el filtro no deberías comparar iguales, sino inclusiones: `SELECT col1 WHERE col1 CONTAINS 4` o, más *pythónico*, `SELECT col1 WHERE 4 IN col1`. Concretamente, ¿hay que entender que lo que usas es básicamente un diccionario cuyos items son listas de cosas?

Comment: Se nos plantea como norma a seguir emplear las querys: SELECT col1 WHERE = 4. Obviamente el lenguaje más correcto sería el que me has mencionado. En cuanto a la cuestión, sí, solamente estará formado por listas. Aunque solamente vaya a insertar un elemento, este se introducirá en la cabeza de la lista.

Comment: Inicializa cada elemento del diccionario con una lista vacía `[]`, por ejemplo `self.db[clave]=[]` y luego añade a esa lista mediante `self.db[clave].append(dato)`. Si `dato` es una lista, usa `extend()` en vez de `append()`, para que añada los elementos que haya en `dato` (en lugar de añadirlo como otra lista dentro de la primera).

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer esto:
lo que hariamos seria tomar todos los elementos que llegen validar si existe la columna e insertar 1 a 1 en la posicion 0 cada elemento!
en caso contrario crearla a partir de los elementos que nos llegen

```
insert(self,col,data):
   if(self.db[col]):
      for x in data.reverse():
        self.db[col].insert(0,x)
   else:
      self.db[col] = data
```

se le da un reverse() porque si nos llega [1,2,3] no los inserte [3,2,1]

Answer (score 0):

Tengo dudas de si estamos hablando de lo mismo. Dices que quieres *insertar* un elemento al principio de una lista, pero también hablas de que tienes *"una clase lista definida en un fichero .py"* y el ejemplo los elementos se están insertando al final de la lista.

Voy a suponer que tu clase lista se basa en las listas normales de python, con lo que insertar un elemento al principio de la lista se puede hacer de varias formas:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
lst.insert(0, 4) # lst == [4,1,2,3]
lst = [5] + lst  # lst == [5,4,1,2,3]
lst[0:0] = 6  # lst == [6,5,4,1,2,3]
```

Como ya te han sugerido, basta inicializar los items del diccionario con la lista vacía `[]` para poder insertar elementos:

```
db = {
 "col1": [],
 "col2": [],
 "col3": [],
}

db["col1"].insert(0, "coche")
db["col2"].insert(0, (1,6,'a',1))
db["col3"].insert(0, 2)
```

Si no es esto lo que querías, completa tu pregunta con algo más de información y código que podamos probar.